# Update devise user using API, security issues

Tags: ruby-on-rails, api, security, ruby-on-rails-4, devise

I need to provide a way to update, via API, some user informations in the mobile app like email, name and also the password(is optional; [solution](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To%3a-Allow-users-to-edit-their-account-without-providing-a-password) for that).

My problem is that because I'm using the API to change those data, how do I keep this secure ? what is the solution for updating the information only if my user is logged on the app. And how my API would know that it really is the user trying to change his informations and not someone trying to hack or something.

I'm using Rails 4 and Devise for authentication.

Answer (score 0):

While signup and login generate a authentication token and send in the response.
Once the token is received by the app it can store it in local storage and will send this authentication token every time it sends a request to the server. This is how you will get to know that the user authentic and when the user logs out of the app delete that token from the app's local storage.